# Column Scrolling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I  have 3 column on my web page like facebook as well as in this example.

https://benfrain.com/playground/scroll-test.html

What i want is when i start scrolling down all columns should scroll down and if anyone of these columns reach at end of its data that column should stop scrolling there while other columns are still scrolling. Now Suppose if first and third column reached to its end and stopped scrolling but second column  still have some data down and still scrolling , When i start scrolling up, first and third column also need to start scrolling up immediately and will stop again whenever first and second column again reached to its full top.
How can i achieve this.
I build this page with reactjs and bootstrap .

```js
$(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    $('.content').append('<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas vitae pretium ante. Pellentesque eu quam non eros fermentum euismod. Sed turpis ligula, hendrerit at erat at, mattis commodo tortor. Sed eleifend velit interdum augue faucibus luctus. Nulla facilisi. Fusce facilisis at enim ac euismod. Vestibulum a lobortis velit. Sed ac erat ac sapien rhoncus tristique. Aliquam eget diam non justo sollicitudin egestas. Cras aliquam egestas nunc sed fermentum. Donec nec consectetur neque. Proin arcu ligula, tincidunt a augue in, dictum pharetra nisi.</p>');
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  position: relative;
}

#container {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
}

#inner {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
}

#inner>div {
  display: table-cell;
}

#palette {
  min-width: 180px;
  max-width: 180px;
  width: 180px !important;
  background-color: pink;
}

#list {
  width: 55%;
  min-width: 350px;
  background-color: cyan;
}

#editor {
  width: 45%;
  min-width: 400px;
  background-color: magenta;
}

.content {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="inner">
    <div id="palette">palette</div>
    <div id="list">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="editor">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should provide some code example of what you have tried, so that people can better understand your problem and try to help

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KdZ9A/2/
Please check this example on jsfiddle i have exactly the same code . In simple words I just want when I scroll second column down it should also scroll third column down and vice versa